# How to use a variable inside mktime in awk?

Tags: awk, sed

I have variable `timeData` which has a value as given below in awk

```
$(f["DateTime"])="2018-12-17 15:10:19"

timeData = gensub(/[-:]/," ","g",$(f["DateTime"]))
```

I need to use  `mktime(timeData)` so that it will give the time in seconds,

```
temp = mktime(timeData)
```

Printing the value of temp gives `-1` as output, I think the issue is not using double quotes inside the mktime, Could anyone tell me how to use that in awk.

Comment: **`mktime(datespec [, utc-flag ])`**
Turn `datespec` into a timestamp in the same form as is returned by `systime()`. It is similar to the function of the same name in ISO C. **The argument, `datespec`, is a string** of the form `"YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]"`. The string consists of six or seven numbers representing, respectively, the full year including century, the month from 1 to 12, the day of the month from 1 to 31, the hour of the day from 0 to 23, the minute from 0 to 59, the second from 0 to 60,55 and an optional daylight-savings flag. (source `man gawk`)

Comment: Please don't start a whole new question when you're just trying to solve a problem you're having running a potential solution to your existing question. Also - why would you tag your question with `sed` when it's very specifically about using a GNU awk function?

Comment: Sorry, I will remove this question and continue the discussion in the existing question

Answer (score 4):

Your code is perfectly fine as-is, assuming you're using GNU awk. If you have an issue then it's related to your input data, not your code, and it certainly has nothing to do with adding double quotes inside mktime():

```
awk 'BEGIN {
$(f["DateTime"])="2018-12-17 15:10:19"

timeData = gensub(/[-:]/," ","g",$(f["DateTime"]))

temp = mktime(timeData)

print timeData, "->", temp
}'
2018 12 17 15 10 19 -> 1545081019
```

Comment: The suggestions for the double quotes were a consequence of the original question. The question is now completely different (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54306089/3)).

Comment: Ah, I see. I had the same problem of revolving requirements with the OPs original question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/54300519/1745001) and eventually gave up.

Answer (score 2):

Watch  this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{temp=2018 12 26 11 54 43; temp2="2018 12 26 11 54 43"; print temp; print temp2; print mktime(temp2);}'
20181226115443
2018 12 26 11 54 43
1545796483
```

You're bascially doing right, but...
It's because you didn't put quotes around the date you are assigning, thus they got concatenated.

Comment: To be more precise, the operations `expr expr` concatenates **strings**. Thus, the expression `temp=2018 12 26 11 54 43` will fist convert all integers to strings and then concatenate those strings.

Comment: @kvantour Can you tell  me how to do this now, I have edited my question which might give more clarity, 
timeData = "gensub(/[-:]/," ","g",$(f["DateTime"]))" putting gensub inside double quotes is not working.